# Building weighted undirected graphs with SNAP library

Tags: python, c++, undirected-graph

I have been tasked with building & visualising a graph network consisting of hundreds of millions of nodes and billions of edges.I found snap library very useful for this purpose as it is developed for handling same situation.

The graph should be undirected and should have weighted edges.I read the snap documentation but couldn't find a way to assign weights to edges in an undirected graph.
What should I do now?

Data I am using is in csv format